# Can I watch iTunes-purchased movies using Windows Media Center on a Windows Home Server?

Tags: itunes, windows-media-center, windows-home-server, hp-mediasmart

I recently purchased and set up a new Windows Home Server machine. I'd like to purchase some movies from the iTunes store to stream from my Home Server to my television. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any TV that supports iTunes DRM you may want to invest in Apple TV if you have some spare cash and plan on doing this often.  Or if you have a spare computer for HTPC install iTunes on the WHS machine and share that way or just install it on the machine you plan on watching it on and share out a folder.